# How to identify whether my data follows "Missing At Random" (MAR) mechanism or not?

Tags: regression, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mcar

I was having two similar studies with two variables (anti-gE and anti-VZV (continuous variable)) linearly related to each other (with same relationship between both the studies in anti-gE and anti-VZV) respectively.In one of the study all values of anti-gE is removed and then these two studies are combined in following way[image: so the box in grey color is with missing data]. Is this mentioned missing is (MAR) or not if yes how?
I am think that since missing at random is when the probability of missing data on a variable is related to some other measured variable, but not the variable itself, i.e. here the probability of missing log anti-gE is related to the measured variable log anti-VZV of study 1

Comment: Missing at random described a mechanism that lead to the missing data, where the process was "random", "unrelated to data". I don't see how this could be applied at all to the scenario you are describing? Could you clarify why would you think of this as missing at random? How are you going to use this data?

Comment: since missing at random is when the probability of missing data on a variable is related to some other measured variable, but not the variable itself, i.e. here the probability of missing log anti-gE is related to the measured variable log anti-VZV of study 1